# Angular material snackbar is not working, don't have any error in cli

Tags: angular, function, angular-material, subscribe, snackbar

```
addtoCart(product: Product): void {
 // console.log("Product Added to cart ", product) 
 this.cartservice.addToCart(product).subscribe({
 next: () =\> {
   console.log("Product Added to cart ", product)
   this.snackbar.open("Product Added to Cart", "", {
     duration: 2000,
     horizontalPosition: 'right',
     verticalPosition: 'top'
   })
  }
})
```

}

```
addToCart(product: Product): Observable\<Product\> {
  return this.http.post\<Product\>(this.apiUrl, product)
}
```

in my cli i don't have any error. it is getting compiled without any errors.

i tried to debug by, console.log getting the product details.

The above function is not working properly it is getting stuck at the  this.cartservice.addToCart(product).subscribe snackbar is not popping up.

Comment: is it a standalone component? check your imports if not show how you injected the snackbar

Comment: it is angular material imported using api                                                                                import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

Comment: constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

Comment: done the same thing before only, function is not working

Comment: Could you please try to reproduce the issue using https://stackblitz.com/? From the provided code example, it is pretty challenging to determine the bug.

Comment: sure i will check from stackblitz